# Fixing Checkbox in React project

Tags: java, reactjs

Pretty new to StackOverflow, and also React.js, so I appreciate anyone that can help me out with this.

I'm wondering how to fix the checkmark for my To-do items, as when I try to run it with the Springboot server it does not seem to update (check and uncheck).

My backend code is very simple code as at the moment I am using an ArrayList as a local database before I implement a proper RDBMS.

I only have one component being the TodoItem in the frontend, and I am wondering if somehow that is where my error has occurred?

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    
    const TodoItem = (props) => {
        // Never update the getter in REACT, instead use the setter method
        const [todoItem, setTodoItem] = useState(props.data);
        const [isDirty, setDirty] = useState(false); // True when a change to the todo item has occurred
    
        // Hook to keep track of updates to the TodoItem
        // When state changes for TodoItem, update data in server to represent change
    
        useEffect(() => { // This occurs when the todoItem changes and (isDirty) and handles updating the items in the backend
            console.log("Item changed",todoItem);
            if (isDirty) {
                fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/todoItems/${todoItem.id}`, {
                    method: "PUT",
                    headers: {
                        "content-type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(todoItem),
                })
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        setDirty(false);
                        setTodoItem(data);
                    });
            }
        }, [todoItem, isDirty]);
    
        function updateTask (event){
            setDirty(true);
            setTodoItem({...todoItem, task: event.target.value});
        }
        
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={todoItem.isCompleted}
                    onChange={() => {
                        setDirty(true);
                        setTodoItem({...todoItem, isCompleted: !todoItem.isCompleted})
                    }}
                />
                <input type = "text" value ={todoItem.task} onChange={updateTask}/>
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default TodoItem;
```

I will also include the App.js below, just in case.

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TodoItem from './Components/todoItem';

function App() {

  const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // This is the onLoad/do something when app loads up
    console.log("Loaded up");

    // If there are no todoItems, fetch items for the onLoad
    if (!todoItems) {
      fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/todoItems")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log("To do items list: ", data);
          // Update items to show them
          setTodoItems(data);
        });
    }
  }, [todoItems]);

  function addNewItem(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/todoItems", {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST' 
    }).then((response)  => response.json()) // promise to take the response and translate it into javascript object, returns another promise
      .then((newTodoItem) => {
        console.log(newTodoItem);
        // Update the state, to show the recieved TodoItem
        setTodoItems([...todoItems, newTodoItem]);
      });
  }


  return (
    <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={addNewItem}> Add New Item </button>
    </div>

      <div>
        {todoItems
          ? todoItems.map((todoItem) => {
            return <TodoItem key={todoItem.id} data={todoItem} />;
          })
          : 'Need to fetch items...'}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The code looks fine so it might be an issue in the server. By the way, in the way you're using it, you don't need the `isDirty` state since your `useEffect` hook will only run again if the `todoItem` value changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man ill take your advice and have a look at the server. Since I am updating the todoItem at the end of the 'useEffect' hook, I thought I had to use the 'isDirty' state to prevent an infinite loop. I'll have another look at that too then

Comment: yes, didn't see that last call to `setTodoItem`. In this case, it'd be better for you to listen individually to the properties you're interested in (like `todoItem.name`) instead of the whole object.